# How to properly change the Chef::Config[:file_cache_path] in .kitchen.yml?

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

I'm stumped.  I want to change the cache location.  The default is in the user profile temp folder; it makes for a VERY long path on Windows.  I have looked over all the docs; and I can't seem to figure this out.

[Here](https://docs.chef.io/config_yml_kitchen.html) I see that I can specify `client.rb` settings on the `chef-solo` provisioner.
and [here](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_client.html) I see that the cache path is a setting in the `client.rb` specified by `cache_path`.
This leads me to believe that I should be able to:

```yaml
provisioner:
  name: chef_solo
  client_rb:
    cache_path: c:/chef/cache
```

But this does not seem to work :(  Can anyone tell me the correct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I have been using the following without issue for a couple weeks now; so I will go ahead and put the solution that I've found incase it helps anyone else:

```
provisioner:
  name: chef_solo
  solo_rb:
    file_cache_path: 'c:\chef\cache'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, this is deeply controlled by Test Kitchen. Why do you think you need to change this?

Comment: Thanks @coderanger -
1)  it makes for a VERY long path on Windows
2)  When the run is done as Administrator, the profile path is shortened to `ADMINI~1` which, for reasons I don't understand, breaks the silent installation of certain softwares (MSSQL currently)

Comment: I'm not sure we have a great solution for this other than to use a different path for the download.

Comment: Try using `file_cache_path` as the key under `client_rb`? That might affect some bits, but could leave Kitchen in a broken state too.

Comment: I have played around a bit more with this and I think I have solved it, but would appreciate any feedback on the method I'm using.  I don't think this has broken anything...
```
provisioner:
  name: chef_solo
  solo_rb:
    file_cache_path: 'c:\chef\cache'
```